# SQL Querying subscribers older than 6 months

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, data-views

I am trying to query data from an existing data extension into a new data extension and filter out the subscribers that were added within the last six months. The existing data extension does not have a date joined column, thus I am trying to query the `_Subscribers` data view to get this info. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Data_Extension
WHERE CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) as smalldatetime) <=
(
    SELECT DateJoined
    FROM _Subscribers
)
```

The syntax is valid, but somehow I am getting 0 subscribers in my target data extension which is not possible. How can I fix my query?

Comment: Remember to add a prefix of "ENT" if you're running the query from a child BU : ENT._Subscribers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a sub query, you will want to use a join to the subscriber data view. For example:

```
Select de.* from mydataextension de 
Join _subscribers s 
On s.subscriberkey = de.subscriberkey
Where s.datejoined <= dateadd(m,-6,getdate())
```

Comment: thanks, your code worked after I changed the `JOIN` line to `JOIN ENT._Subscribers s` as suggested by @jclobro